# How to construct a new column based on other columns in a SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have this table:

```
Assets
--------------------------------
Description VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
Suffix1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
UseSuffix1 BIT NOT NULL
Suffix2 VARCHAR(50) NULL
UseSuffix2 BIT NOT NULL
Suffix3 VARCHAR(50) NULL
UseSuffix3 BIT NOT NULL
```

I am trying to do a `SELECT` statement that constructs the following: a VARCHAR(MAX) columns that consists of the `Description` field, plus the other suffixes appended when required (via the UseSuffixX flag)

examples of input and output :

```
'MyDesc'
'Suffix1'
0
NULL                 ->     'MyDesc'
0
NULL
0
-----------------------
'MyDesc'
'Suffix1'
1
NULL                 ->     'MyDesc - Suffix1'
0
NULL
0
-----------------------
'MyDesc'
'Suffix1'
0
'Suffix2'            ->     'MyDesc - Suffix2 - Suffix 3'
1
'Suffix3'
1
-----------------------
'MyDesc'
'Suffix1'
1
'Suffix2'            ->     'MyDesc - Suffix1 - Suffix 3'
0
'Suffix3'
1
```

I started by using a `CASE` directive in my `SELECT` like this:

```
SELECT
    [Description] + 
    CASE 
        WHEN UseSuffix1 = 1 THEN ' - ' + Suffix1
        WHEN UseSuffix2 = 1 THEN ' - ' + Suffix2
        WHEN UseSuffix3 = 1 THEN ' - ' + Suffix3
        ELSE ''
    END
FROM Assets
```

but quickly realized that I would need to expand the trees of all possibilities in each `WHEN` branch...not sure if I'm expressing myself correctly here.

What would be the more practical way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need all the possibilities, just one `case` per suffix:

```
SELECT ([Description] + 
        (CASE WHEN UseSuffix1 = 1 THEN ' - ' + Suffix1 ELSE '' END) +
        (CASE WHEN UseSuffix2 = 1 THEN ' - ' + Suffix2 ELSE '' END) +
        (CASE WHEN UseSuffix3 = 1 THEN ' - ' + Suffix3 ELSE '' END) 
       )
FROM Assets
```